# How to list taxonomy terms with custom sort (glossary view)?

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to create a taxonomy terms list with glossary view. Normally, everything is working (page view, attachment, contextual filter (glossary view) etc).

My taxonomy terms are full names, such as: Ali Veli, Mehmet Zeki

In glossary view it seperates the letter with the first letter and it seems like that:

**A | B | C | ... | M | ... | Z**

**A**

Ali Veli

...

**M**

Mehmet Zeki

I want to sort all the terms by surnames (last word of term) instead of names (first word of term).

**A | B | C | ... | M | ... | Z**

**V**

Veli, Ali

...

**Z**

Zeki, Mehmet

If I don't use the contextual filter and glossary view I could use [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) and do what I want as this:

**1.** I added the Taxonomy Term: Name field.

**2.** I added a Global: PHP field.

This is the value code:

```
$exploded = explode (" ", $row->name);
$exploded_last = array_pop($exploded);
$eachone = $exploded_last .', ' .implode(' ', $exploded);
return $eachone;
```

This is the output code:

```
<?php print $value; ?>
```

**3.** I added a new Global: PHP sorting field to Sorting Criteria.

This is the sort code:

```
if ($row1->php < $row2->php) return -1; else return 1;
```

This method is working good (without contextual filter & glossary view) and gives the results as this:

Veli, Ali

Zeki, Mehmet

**How can I use such a method for glossary view?**

Comment: Any idea for this? I can't use this method for glossary views.

Comment: Can you build a View to do what you want?

Comment: @Brady, sorry couldn't understand. What do you mean by _"Can you build a View to do what you want?"_

Comment: Can you build a View in Views to do what you want? If you can then there are ways to override Taxonomy displays with views.